# Can I temporarily store data in my C#.Net app to reduce the need for calls for data from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I created a C#.net app that uses dates from a SQL Server 2008 database table.  Is there a way for me to temporarily store the data so that my program does not have to repeatedly make server calls for the same set of information? I know how to pull the info I need and create a temporary dataset, however, it is only accessible to the particular method or class and then goes away.  I need the results to be universally available until the program closes.

This is what I have so far and I am not sure where to go next:

```
SqlConnection ReportConnect = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
String reportQuery = @"SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM dbo.myTable ORDER BY DATE DESC";

ReportConnect.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = ReportConnect.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = ReportConnect;
cmd.CommandText = reportQuery.ToString();

SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(rdr.Read()) {
   //I can access the results here 
}

//how do I add this data for the life of the program instance to my current
//dataset.  Let's say the dataset is named "activeDataset"
```

Comment: This would be called caching the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a singleton object, and store the data in this object.

*Be aware that there is a lot more to single ton objects that you will have to think about.*

Have a look at

- [Implementing the Singleton Pattern
  in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html)
- [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)
- [Implementing Singleton in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998558.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to use key/value pair caching, I recommend you use [HttpRuntime.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache(lightweight).aspx) (available outside ASP.NET applications) since it already does alot of work for you.

In it's simplest implementation:

```
public IList<DateTime> GetUniqueDates()
{
    const string CacheKey = "RepositoryName.UniqueDates";

    Cache cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;

    List<DateTime> result = cache.Get[CacheKey] as List<DateTime>;

    if (result == null)
    {
        // If you're application has multithreaded access to data, you might want to 
        // put a double lock check in here

        using (SqlConnection reportConnect = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            // ...
            result = new List<DateTime>();

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                result.Add((DateTime)reader["Value"]);
            }
        }

        // You can specify various timeout options here
        cache.Insert(CacheKey, result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Having said that, I usually use IoC trickery to create a caching layer in front of my repository for the sake of cohesion.

Comment: `ObjectCache` / `MemoryCache` is the most appropriate post-.NET 4 object to use and is also available outside ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

You should use SQLCacheDependency. Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could store the datatable in a static variable that would be accesible from any part of your code (is this necessary?).

```
public class MyDataSetCache
{
    public static DataSet MyDataSet { get; set; }
}
```

Some other code...

```
// SQL Statements....
MyDataSetCache.MyDataSet = activeDataset // Editted to follow OP :-)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the help and the detailed explanation.  Yes the details are necessary for me.  Thanks for including them.

Comment: Glad I could help. Doesn't sound like it's an issue here but the code above is not necessarily thread safe. The links in @astander's answer go into more detail about this and should be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can definately use Cache to reduce database hits, Besides using SqlDependency you can have a cache based on time. You can invalidate your cache let's say every 4 hours,and hit the database again. Check out Cache.Insert()

Comment: Sorry Volkan, I acceidently added a code sample to the wrong answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I usually serialize whole object to a file and try to read it first before going to database.

Comment: I thought about doing this. Is it a lot faster to access a text or xml file than sql server? I would guess so, but I have not tested to see?

Comment: Sure. Local call is always faster than remote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set of implementation hooks to achieve result:

1. Common data-application layer (data singleton or some data coupling using static class with lesser "visible" methods' dependencies)
2. Use caching -- you can use [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) and common string-keys to detect (`ContainsKey` method) whether data is already fetched or needs sql-server call. This can be useful when you need different `DataSet`s. Dictionary works pretty fast.